# How can I automatically generate composite images by layering source images randomly?

Tags: image-processing, scripting, imagemagick, photoshop

I am working on a personal creative project and need help finding or creating a script that will randomly select 4 images from 4 different folders, stack them and create a series of png composite images as an output. Extra points if the images of each folder can be assigned to a fixed layer (so, for example, images from the "backgrounds" folder will always appear in the back).
Note: I don't know how to code.

Comment: Are you on a decent OS like Linux or OSX? What if the images are different sizes - rescale to a fixed size?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. I'm working on OSX, my source images are all png with alpha channel saved at the final size, so no need to make changes. The final images should have 4 layers, I have a set of images for each one of the layers on separate folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

Ok, I have updated the script as follows:

1. It produces 10 output files - you can change it by altering NFILES at the start
2. The output files will not overwrite each other between runs, the next free name will be used starting with `output-0.png` then `output-1.png` and so on.
3. I have corrected the alpha compositing to match your files.

Script follows...

```
#!/bin/bash

# Number of output files - edit freely :-)
NFILES=10

# Build arrays of filenames in each layer, assume directories are "Layer0", "Layer1" etc
IFS=$'\n' L0files=($(find "Layer 0" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L1files=($(find "Layer 1" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L2files=($(find "Layer 2" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L3files=($(find "Layer 3" -name "*.png"))

# Produce NFILES output files
for i in `seq 1 $NFILES`; do

   # Choose random index into each array of filenames
   index0=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L0files[@]} - 1)) )
   index1=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L1files[@]} - 1)) )
   index2=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L2files[@]} - 1)) )
   index3=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L3files[@]} - 1)) )

   # Pick up files as specified by the random index
   f0=${L0files[index0]}
   f1=${L1files[index1]}
   f2=${L2files[index2]}
   f3=${L3files[index3]}

   # Generate output filename, "output-nnn.png" 
   # ... where nnn starts at 0 and goes up till no clash
   i=0
   while :; do
      out="output-$i.png"
      [ ! -f "$out" ] && break
      ((i++))
   done

   echo $f0, $f1, $f2, $f3 "=> $out"
   convert "$f0" "$f1" -composite "$f2" -composite "$f3" -composite "$out"
done
```

Starting with the following images in your Layer[0-3] directories:

**Layer 0**

[image]

**Layer 1**

[image]

**Layer 2**

[image]

**Layer 3**

[image]

Output files like the following are produced:

[image]

**Original Answer**

I would install ImageMagick to do this - it is free and easily installed on OSX if you install `homebrew` first by going [here](http://brew.sh). Then type the following in Terminal.

```
brew install imagemagick
```

The script would then look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Build arrays of filenames in each layer, assume directories are "Layer0", "Layer1" etc
IFS=$'\n' L0files=($(find "Layer0" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L1files=($(find "Layer1" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L2files=($(find "Layer2" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L3files=($(find "Layer3" -name "*.png"))

# Choose random index into each array of filenames
index0=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L0files[@]} - 1)) )
index1=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L1files[@]} - 1)) )
index2=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L2files[@]} - 1)) )
index3=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L3files[@]} - 1)) )

# Pick up files as specified by the random index
f0=${L0files[index0]}
f1=${L1files[index1]}
f2=${L2files[index2]}
f3=${L3files[index3]}

echo Overlaying $f0, $f1, $f2, $f3 to produce "result.png"
convert "$f0" "$f1" "$f2" "$f3" -compose over -composite result.png
```

So, you would save the above as `generate` and then go to Terminal and do the following one time to make it executable

```
chmod +x generate
```

Then you can run it by double-clicking on its icon in Finder, or typing:

```
./generate
```

in Terminal. It will then produce a random overlay of 4 images, one from each folder and save the result as `result.png`.

You will need to edit the first 4 lines according to where your images are for the various layers - basically I am assuming the images are in directories called `Layer0-4`, but yours may be in `/Users/FreddyFrog/pictures/backgrounds` or somesuch, in which case you would edit

```
    IFS=$'\n' L0files=($(find "/Users/FreddyFrog/pictures/backgrounds" -name "*.png"))
```

When I run it a few times on my Mac, I get:

```
Overlaying Layer0/l0-5.png, Layer1/l1-0.png, Layer2/l2-3.png, Layer3/l3-3.png to produce result.png
Overlaying Layer0/l0-3.png, Layer1/l1-4.png, Layer2/l2-3.png, Layer3/l3-3.png to produce result.png
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @Mark, this seems to address the main task. I am having problems with the way transparencies are rendered though, I can only see 2 layers at a time, and my flat color backgrounds seem to cover the forefront image.<br> As I need to run the script several times, how can I avoid the result being overwritten and how can i make it play maybe let's say 10 times every time I run it?

Comment: I'm not at my Mac for a while. Can you post an image from each layer and your expected result please? Or click my profile and Email them and how the result should look. I can address all issues then when home.

Comment: Thanks again. I have uploaded a sample of the 4 layers and an example result image [here](http://we.tl/MKIpQvKwXd)

Comment: I think this now addresses all your requests - just say if anything is wrong or unclear for your needs.

Comment: @ign: The generally recommended way to say "Thank you" on StackOverflow is to 'upvote' any answer that you come across and read and think it is one which is good or which taught you something new. You 'accepted' Mark's answer only, but you didn't 'upvote' it yet (as I myself did just now). Upvoting is done by clicking on the **`^`**-shaped icon at the top left of an answer.

Comment: Hi @KurtPfeifle, thanks for noting this. I did try to upvote the answer, but apparently I haven't gathered enough reputation yet to do so. Still I would like to express my gratitude in a way that works for this community.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I posted a thank you note yesterday, but can't see it now, so I'd like to make sure that you know that this answer solved my problem and saved me a few of days of work, will upvote as soon as I have enough reputation. Merry Christmas!

Comment: My pleasure - glad to be of help and a Merry Christmas to you too.