# How can I automatically generate composite images by layering source images randomly in Windows?

Tags: windows, image-processing, scripting, imagemagick

Hi I'm interested to know how to do image composite of few image randomly from a set of different folder. I think this the answer by [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617988/how-can-i-automatically-generate-composite-images-by-layering-source-images-rand) answered my question but I'm on windows and I do not understand how to use this script in BAT file in Windows. I dont have clue about $ in the unix code or if i even mentioning it correctly.

Thank you in advance.

**Updated:**

I have finally able to make this works. Thanks also to other thread to solve my bat command script problem.

```
echo OFF
cls
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /a folder1=1
for %%A in (./bg/*.png) do (set fol1[!folder1!]=%%~A
set /a folder1+=1 )

set /a folder2=1
for %%B in (./frame/*.png) do (set fol2[!folder2!]=%%~B
set /a folder2+=1 )

set /a folder3=1
for %%C in (./people/*.png) do (set fol3[!folder3!]=%%~C
set /a folder3+=1 )

set /a folder4=1
for %%D in (./box/*.png) do (set fol4[!folder4!]=%%~D
set /a folder4+=1 )


set totaloutput=10

for /l %%x in (1, 1, %totaloutput%) do (

    :: Assigning random number to pick photos from array
    set /a "_rand1=(!RANDOM!* (%folder1%-1) /32768)+1"
    set /a "_rand2=(!RANDOM! * (%folder2%-1) /32768)+1"
    set /a "_rand3=(!RANDOM! * (%folder3%-1) /32768)+1"
    set /a "_rand4=(!RANDOM! * (%folder4%-1) /32768)+1"
    
    :: Assigning filename with path to the picked photos
    FOR %%A IN ("!_rand1!") DO set "file1=.\bg\!fol1[%%~A]!"
    FOR %%B IN ("!_rand2!") DO set "file2=.\frame\!fol2[%%~B]!"
    FOR %%C IN ("!_rand3!") DO set "file3=.\people\!fol3[%%~C]!"
    FOR %%D IN ("!_rand4!") DO set "file4=.\box\!fol4[%%~D]!"
    
    :: Assign output file numbering based on FOR iteration number
    set "fileoutput=output-%%~x.png"
    
    :: Final Magic
    magick convert !file1! !file2! -composite !file3! -composite !file4! -composite !fileoutput!
    
)
```

Output Sample:

[sample output of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Qrg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repost as an answer:

```
echo OFF
cls
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /a folder1=1
for %%A in (./bg/*.png) do (set fol1[!folder1!]=%%~A
set /a folder1+=1 )

set /a folder2=1
for %%B in (./frame/*.png) do (set fol2[!folder2!]=%%~B
set /a folder2+=1 )

set /a folder3=1
for %%C in (./people/*.png) do (set fol3[!folder3!]=%%~C
set /a folder3+=1 )

set /a folder4=1
for %%D in (./box/*.png) do (set fol4[!folder4!]=%%~D
set /a folder4+=1 )


set totaloutput=10

for /l %%x in (1, 1, %totaloutput%) do (

    :: Assigning random number to pick photos from array
    set /a "_rand1=(!RANDOM!* (%folder1%-1) /32768)+1"
    set /a "_rand2=(!RANDOM! * (%folder2%-1) /32768)+1"
    set /a "_rand3=(!RANDOM! * (%folder3%-1) /32768)+1"
    set /a "_rand4=(!RANDOM! * (%folder4%-1) /32768)+1"
    
    :: Assigning filename with path to the picked photos
    FOR %%A IN ("!_rand1!") DO set "file1=.\bg\!fol1[%%~A]!"
    FOR %%B IN ("!_rand2!") DO set "file2=.\frame\!fol2[%%~B]!"
    FOR %%C IN ("!_rand3!") DO set "file3=.\people\!fol3[%%~C]!"
    FOR %%D IN ("!_rand4!") DO set "file4=.\box\!fol4[%%~D]!"
    
    :: Assign output file numbering based on FOR iteration number
    set "fileoutput=output-%%~x.png"
    
    :: Final Magic
    magick convert !file1! !file2! -composite !file3! -composite !file4! -composite !fileoutput!
    
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak *"Windows"*, but can give you half an answer, which you or somebody else can hopefully expand out into something that works.

The basic **ImageMagick** command you will need to run is:

```
magick BACKGROUND.PNG OVERLAY1.PNG OVERLAY2.PNG -compose over -composite RESULT.PNG
```

If you want to resize them all to the same size before overlaying, use:

```
magick BACKGROUND.PNG OVERLAY1.PNG OVERLAY2.PNG -resize 800x600! -compose over -composite RESULT.PNG
```

If you want to resize them individually before overlaying, use:

```
magick BACKGROUND.PNG ( OVERLAY1.PNG -resize 400x300 ) ( OVERLAY2.PNG -resize 100x100 ) -compose over -composite RESULT.PNG
```

So try that with some of your images and see what you get. Update your question with your code and representative sample images.

Comment: Appreciate your gesture to reply with the hints even though you don't speak "Windows". My issue was most with bat command scripting