# How to create single image from a number of images in different folders

Tags: arrays, image, layer, generate

My coding knowledge is zero, just to preface all of this. I'd like to create a large number of randomly generated images, made up of 6 components. Each folder holds one set of the images eg. Folder 1: Backgrounds... I'd like the images to be randomly selected from within each folder, but used in order from Folder 1 through 6. I don't know if this is simple enough, but I have no idea what I'm doing, staring at Python for the last 3 days. Is there any chance someone could put this together, if its not something that's actually much harder than I realise how to do?
If anyone answers this, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69100090/2836621

Comment: Thanks mate, sorry for responding late, got it done.