# Automatically generate random compositions by layering source images **without creating duplicates**

Tags: image-processing, scripting, duplicates, imagemagick, photoshop

This is a follow on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617988/how-can-i-automatically-generate-composite-images-by-layering-source-images-rand/27621140#27621140?newreg=9c8b5b147962401a972b76169f3120e3) asked by [ign](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4388124/ign) and expertly answered by [Marc Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell)

It works perfectly, though I am hoping to find a way to avoid duplicates forming in the randomisation process. I am going to be doing hundreds of variations of a bunch of layers, with subtle differences, so I can't really go in and spot duplicates in a fail-safe way.

Here is the code I'm using, as per above - all credit to Marc Setchell!

```
#!/bin/bash

# Number of output files - edit freely :-)
NFILES=10

# Build arrays of filenames in each layer, assume directories are "Layer0", "Layer1" etc
IFS=$'\n' L0files=($(find "Layer 0" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L1files=($(find "Layer 1" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L2files=($(find "Layer 2" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L3files=($(find "Layer 3" -name "*.png"))

# Produce NFILES output files
for i in `seq 1 $NFILES`; do

   # Choose random index into each array of filenames
   index0=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L0files[@]} - 1)) )
   index1=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L1files[@]} - 1)) )
   index2=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L2files[@]} - 1)) )
   index3=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L3files[@]} - 1)) )

   # Pick up files as specified by the random index
   f0=${L0files[index0]}
   f1=${L1files[index1]}
   f2=${L2files[index2]}
   f3=${L3files[index3]}

   # Generate output filename, "output-nnn.png" 
   # ... where nnn starts at 0 and goes up till no clash
   i=0
   while :; do
      out="output-$i.png"
      [ ! -f "$out" ] && break
      ((i++))
   done

   echo $f0, $f1, $f2, $f3 "=> $out"
   convert "$f0" "$f1" -composite "$f2" -composite "$f3" -composite "$out"
done
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am looking to have the code above - that layers mulptiple pngs in order to create random image compositions - edited, in order to avoid producing duplicates during the randomization. @xenoid was very helpful in how to change the output file name, which is fantastic, but it now pauses if it is trying to create a duplicate image - and will only continue once the original file is moved. So I now just need to know how to make it add a number at the end of the output file name, in order for it to not pause on duplicates. I can then search by name and see where the duplicates are, and delete them.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO nothing to do with IM or PS. Just name your files so that they include the index of the layers you are using to create them, and skip if you see that you are creating the same file again.

```
    out="output-$index0-$index1-$index2-$index3.png"
    [[ ! -f "$out" ]] && continue
    ((i++))
```

This also requires that you don't use `seq 1 $NFILES` to iterate your files since you want to increment the counter only when you don't skip(*).

When you are done you rename your files to a sequence, if necessary.

Another method in bash is to declare an associative array and put an element in it for each file that you create:

```
# declare associative array
declare -A doneFiles

# when creating a file:
combination=$index0-$index1-$index2-$index3
donefiles[$combination]="done" # or any info

# testing:
[[ -n ${doneFiles[$combination]} ]] && continue # already done
```

(*) By the way using `i` for both the outer and inner loops is crazy even if you don't use the outer variable explicitly. But then the inner loop is terrible code, since you can use the outer `i`.

Comment: Wow thank you for the speedy, indepth answer! Really appreciate the help. 

That said, I should have disclosed that I'm very novice to the field. I get what you are saying this should do -having naming done according to the layers that make up each image - this would be the absolute ideal. I just can't figure out how to implant your edit into my code to make it work. 

I did try but think I'm being viciously ignorant at some pivotal step :) 

Note - I need to be able to choose a final number for the output as there is the capacity for thousands if not millions of variations otherwise.

Comment: Just to update - I realise if I keep my current script, and only change the line   `out="output-$index0-$index1-$index2-$index3.png"` it does the name it according to it's sequence, and then I can add something before each `$index` in order to give each folder/layer a specific title. So the only issue I still face is that it pauses if it's about to spit out a duplicate, and only continues once I move the existing file from that directory. Is there a way to auto-add a suffix to the file name on duplicates in order to prevent it from stopping? Thanks again!!

Comment: Remove your inner loop it' not necessary.

Comment: Any chance you might be up for sending me a complete code that I could use please? I've tried to look it up, but i'ts beyond me... can't figure it out. Apologies, I realise this shouldn't be spoon feeding.