# Randomly compose images by layering pngs

Tags: random, imagemagick

I am trying to use Imagemagick v7 to batch create images by randomly combining layers which are transparent pngs, all at the same size.

I am a total newbie so I copied the code I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27621140/17835805

```
#!/bin/bash

# Number of output files - edit freely :-)
NFILES=10

# Build arrays of filenames in each layer, assume directories are "Layer0", "Layer1" etc
IFS=$'\n' L0files=($(find "Layer 0" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L1files=($(find "Layer 1" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L2files=($(find "Layer 2" -name "*.png"))
IFS=$'\n' L3files=($(find "Layer 3" -name "*.png"))

# Produce NFILES output files
for i in `seq 1 $NFILES`; do

   # Choose random index into each array of filenames
   index0=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L0files[@]} - 1)) )
   index1=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L1files[@]} - 1)) )
   index2=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L2files[@]} - 1)) )
   index3=$( jot -r 1  0 $((${#L3files[@]} - 1)) )

   # Pick up files as specified by the random index
   f0=${L0files[index0]}
   f1=${L1files[index1]}
   f2=${L2files[index2]}
   f3=${L3files[index3]}

   # Generate output filename, "output-nnn.png" 
   # ... where nnn starts at 0 and goes up till no clash
   i=0
   while :; do
      out="output-$i.png"
      [ ! -f "$out" ] && break
      ((i++))
   done

   echo $f0, $f1, $f2, $f3 "=> $out"
   convert "$f0" "$f1" -composite "$f2" -composite "$f3" -composite "$out"
done
```

I managed to make it randomly pick my layers but:

1. No files are created in the output folder.
2. No matter what I put for NFILES, it always stops at the first one ("output-o.png").

Would be great if I could also make sure that, once a layer has been randomly picked and used, it is not picked again.
Perhaps deleting the file with ephemeral?

Comment: What platform? If Unix-like, then why not just make a list of images. Then use `sort -R` or `shuf` to randomly shuffle them. Then input the new list to imagemagick and just do `-background none -flatten`

Comment: I am on mac os 10.14
I would try to implement your suggestion but being a total newbie I have no idea where to start, that's why I am basing my solution on existing code…

Comment: What shell are you using on that version of Mac?  If bash (or perhaps zsh), then check to see if you have -R option to sort or shuf.  If so, then you could try `Arr=(lena.jpg mandril3.jpg zelda1.jpg);
list=$(echo ${Arr[*]} | tr " " "\012" | shuf);
echo $list` to randomly shuffle. You can also try sort -R in place of shuf. Replace my list of list images with how every many of your images that you want. Older Macs use an old version of bash, which does not have -R option to sort or shuf. So you would need a newer version of bash or perhaps zsh would allow those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, thanks to the great help of Mark Setchell, finally figured out a solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Number of output files
NFILES=20
BASE="$HOME/foldername"



# Function to read a random line from file, deleting it if required

randomLine () {
   filename=$1; delete=$2

   # Check file is not empty
   declare -i nlines
   nlines=$(wc -l < "$filename")
   if [ $nlines -eq 0 ] ; then
      2>&1 echo "ERROR: $filename is empty"
      exit 1
   fi
   # Read lines into array
   IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines < "$filename"

   # Choose a random line number
   ((sel = RANDOM % nlines))

   # Output result for caller in global variable
   retval="${lines[sel]}"

   # Delete the line if required
   if [ $delete -eq 1 ] ; then
      lines[sel]="JUNK"
      printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]}" | grep -v "JUNK" > "$filename"
   fi
}


# Main program


# Create output directory
mkdir -p "${BASE}/export"

# Build lists of filenames in each layer - write lists in /tmp
for ((layer=1; layer<=6; layer++)) ; do
   find "${BASE}/parts/p${layer}" -name "*.png" > /tmp/L${layer}
done

# Produce NFILES output files
for ((n=0; n<$NFILES; n++)) ; do

   # Pick up files randomly, deleting 2, 4 and 6, reusing others
   randomLine "/tmp/L1" 0; f1="$retval"
   randomLine "/tmp/L2" 1; f2="$retval"
   randomLine "/tmp/L3" 0; f3="$retval"
   randomLine "/tmp/L4" 1; f4="$retval"
   randomLine "/tmp/L5" 0; f5="$retval"
   randomLine "/tmp/L6" 1; f6="$retval"

   # Generate output filename
   for ((i=0;;i++)) ; do
      out="${BASE}/output-$i.png"
      [ ! -f "$out" ] && break
   done

   echo $f1, $f2, $f3, $f4, $f5, $f6 "=> $out"
   convert "$f1" "$f2" -composite "$f3" -composite "$f4" -composite "$f5" -composite "$f6" -composite "$out"

done
```

Answer (score 1):

ok I figured out the problem, I made a simple syntax mistake when copying/pasting the code... so now I managed to output my images, hurray!

The only thing left to do is to make sure that, once a layer has been randomly picked and used, it is not picked again.

How to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Well done! Remove the elements from the array as you consume them https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395103/400632

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell this exactly what I need!
However, I don't know how to add this to my code, total newbie sorry…
should I add    unset -v 'arr[L0files]'    (and so on, one for each array) before the bit that generates the output file? 

Many thanks

Comment: You want to insert 4 lines just above *"Generate output filename"* and the first one will be `del_element=$index0; L0files=( "${L0files[@]:0:$((del_element-1))}" "${L0files[@]:$del_element}" )` The other 3 follow suit but with different index and array name.

Comment: thank you so much for your help.
I have added the lines but now I only get 1 output file and terminal says the following:

$((del_element-1)): substring expression < 0

might be useful to add that I need to have one layer picked and never used again only for some arrays, while for the other arrays it should use layers more than once

thanks again for your help

Comment: You can run your script with `bash -xv YOURSCRIPT` to see what it is doing and what the various variables are to help you debug.

Comment: ok thanks, trying to debug now. 
the first image is created correctly.
after that, the indexes where I added "del_element" all return the same value =1, so the code just lists all the files in my folders but doesn't pick any. then it says "no decode delegate for this image format" and it stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240779/discussion-between-taiman-and-mark-setchell).